# ViewController loses data after custom init

Tags: core-data, viewcontroller, init

So here's the deal: I have a custom UIViewController named FieldFormVC. In order to present it, I call this code:

```
FieldFormVC *fieldFormVC = [[FieldFormVC alloc] initWithFieldForm:(FieldForm *)[self getForm] andManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
fieldFormVC.trackManager = self;

fieldFormVC.thisTrackNumber = currentScreenIndex;
fieldFormVC.textSize = textSize;

[navigationController pushViewController:fieldFormVC animated:YES];
```

Where [self getForm] returns a FieldForm object. The code for the initWithFieldForm: andManagedObjectContext: method is:

```
-(id)initWithFieldForm: (FieldForm *) f  andManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) moc
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        fieldForm = f;
        managedObjectContext = moc;
    }

    return self;

}
```

I set up some breakpoints, and when the initWithFieldForm: andManagedObjectContext: is called, the parameters "f" and "moc" contain actual values. At the end of the method, fieldFormVC has all the values it needs.

Now when it goes back to the first chunk of code and calls

```
fieldFormVC.trackManager = self;
```

All the values in fieldFormVC go to 0x00000000. All the properties of the fieldFormVC are set with @property (nonatomic, retain) and they are @synthesize'd as well.

The strange thing is that I have used similar initWith.. methods that have turned out great, and I've never seen this issue before. If it helps, I am using Core Data in my project, and FieldForm is a certain entity in my model. Thanks for any advice and help!

**Update:**

The getForm method's code:

```
-(NSObject *) getForm
   {
    WrapperForm *wrapperForm = (WrapperForm *)[[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]objectAtIndex:currentScreenIndex.intValue];

    FieldForm *fieldForm = wrapperForm.fieldForm;
    PictureForm *pictureForm = wrapperForm.pictureForm;


    if (fieldForm != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Class: %@", [wrapperForm.fieldForm.class description]);

        return fieldForm;

    }else if(pictureForm != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Class: %@", [wrapperForm.pictureForm.class description]);

        return pictureForm;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Check what happens in the getter for `trackManager`.

Comment: @Mundi Well since the first chunk of code belongs to TrackManager.m, it accesses FieldForm.h 's "@property (nonatomic, retain) TrackManager *trackManager;" line. In fact, fieldFormVC resets it's variables/values before fieldFormVC.trackManager = self; is called.

Comment: It looks strange. Why do you have to cast to `FieldForm` if `getForm` is anyway returning a `FieldForm`?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting to `FieldForm` although your method `getForm` should actually return a `FieldForm` class anyway. Most likely the `getForm` method does not return the correct object.

Comment: I posted the code for [self getForm]. I have a generic WrapperForm object (because of the way the input XML file is setup) which has either a FieldForm or a PictureForm (but not both). Thus the method returns either the FieldForm or the PictureForm.

Comment: Did you check it does indeed return one?

Comment: Yes, I checked, and it returns an object with a memory address that isn't 0x00000000. Also, I checked to make sure that an actual PictureForm or FieldForm was passed into each WrapperForm when parsing the XML. The thing is that the debugger makes it all the way through the initWith.. method flawlessly, then returns the object and moves on to the next line. Before the next line can be completed, the values of the variables in fieldFormVC are set to 0x00000000.

Comment: Still looks like problem with your init procedure. Try `[[FieldForm alloc] init];` and add the attributes one by one.